# Disable past date in HTML5 calendar

Tags: javascript, html, date

Is there any way to prevent the user to select a past date from HTML5 calendar or how to hide the past date in html5 calendar?
I just need the user to select the current date or future, not past date
Can you help me with this, please?
I don't want to use any plugin

```html
<input id="start" type="date" data-date-inline-picker="true" class="form-control" name="date">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by specifying the `min` value to today's date. The date must be in ISO format `(yyyy-mm-dd)`  like this

```html
<input id="start" type="date" data-date-inline-picker="true" class="form-control" name="date" min="2018-01-06">
```

The min and max attributes must be a full date; there's no way to specify "today" or "+0". To do that dynamically, you'll need to use JavaScript or a server-side language like this:

```js
var today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
document.getElementsByName("date")[0].setAttribute('min', today);
```

```html
<input id="start" type="date" data-date-inline-picker="true" class="form-control" name="date" >
```

Comment: Note that *toISOString* returns the UTC date, which will be interpreted by the browser as local, so will be wrong for the period of the host offset each morning for hosts east of Greenwich, or evening for those west. So while the intent is correct, the implementation is flawed.

Comment: @RobG Agreed. In that case we can manually format date as said by `David` in his answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You will need javascript to do it:

```js
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
 if(dd<10){
        dd='0'+dd
    } 
    if(mm<10){
        mm='0'+mm
    } 

today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
document.getElementById("start").setAttribute("min", today);
```

```html
<input id="start" type="date" data-date-inline-picker="true" class="form-control" name="date" min="">
```

Comment: A good answer should include an explanation of why the OP has their issue and how your code fixes it. Upvote for manually formatting the min date. ;-)